# Svelte how to push in components that have different props according to numbers

Tags: svelte

So, I have a little project I am doing for 100 Days of Coding, and I start to notice that the more days I progress, the more of the same thing I have to write, just with 1 difference. Here's an example from my code.

```
<Tasks {...projects.Day1} />
<Tasks {...projects.Day2} />
<Tasks {...projects.Day3} />
```

I want to go all the way to 100, but it's gonna require me to type the same thing 100 times, with one small difference.
I tried using an each loop like this:

```
{#each dataLength as _, i}
      <Tasks {...projects.Day{ i }/>
{/each}
```

But Svelte doesn't accept this. So I have no way of passing in props from different object keys. Is there a way to do this, or is there an alternative?
Here's my full Svelte App
https://github.com/JoshuaPelealu/100DaysOfCode/tree/master/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [bracket notation instead of the dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to access the properties. So:

```
{#each dataLength as _, i}
      <Tasks {...projects[`Day${i}`]}/>
{/each}
```

(This also use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) but you could just have `["Days" + i]` as well)

Notice that this would start by index `0`, so the first one will be `projects.Day0`. If you want to start from `projects.Day1` you have to add `1`:

```
{#each dataLength as _, i}
      <Tasks {...projects[`Day${i + 1}`]}/>
{/each}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why I didn't thought of the bracket notation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```html
{#each Object.keys(projects) as key}
   <Tasks {...projects[key]} />
{/each}
```